# The New Way To Do This (ActiveRecord Aggregations)

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-1.9, aggregation

I have been learning `ActiveRecord` from the book [**Pro Active Record: Databases With Ruby And Rails**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598474). The book is a little bit outdated (published in **2007**), but I have had no problems with it so far until I had gotten up to **aggregations**. The code I have been using to practice this is made up of the following:

- **Simple *sqlite3* database**

  **Class corresponding to the table in that database**

  **Second class which is the "aggregation model" (*Not sure what to call it*) of the first class**

*The code is displayed below:*

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE songs(
id INTEGER PRIMARYKEY AUTOINCREMENTED,
title VARCHAR
);
```

**Ruby:**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:database => "songs.db", :adapter => "sqlite3")
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :songinfo, :class_name => "SongInfo", :mapping => [%w(title title)]
end

class SongInfo
  attr_accessor :title
  def initialize title
    @title = title
  end
end

song.songinfo = SongInfo.new("Purple Haze")
# I first tried it out on an old (school owned) computer, with an outdated version of ActiveRecord.
# When I called the previous line on the school computer, it worked fine, but on my home computer, which is not old, I saw: DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute `title,'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use `attr_writer` etc. 
song.save
song.title
song.title = "Voodoo Child"
song.save
```

When I call the preceding code on my **home computer**, `song.title` returns `nil`, while on the school computer, it returned the **actual title of the song**. Also, on the **school computer**, `Song.find(1)` would return the song with an ID of 1, on the home computer, it returns a very long error message, displayed below:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: songs.: SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs"  WHERE "songs"."" = ? LIMIT 1
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:253:in `block in exec_query'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:242:in `exec_query'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:467:in `select'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:63:in `select_all'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/explain.rb:25:in `logging_query_plan'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/explain.rb:25:in `logging_query_plan'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:376:in `find_first'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:334:in `find_one'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:310:in `find_with_ids'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.4/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
    from (irb):19
    from /Users/Solomon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'1.9.3-p125 :020 >
```

Version Numbers:

- **Ruby**: 1.9.3
- **ActiveRecord**: 3.2.4
- **OS**: OS X Lion 10.7

Any help would be appreciated, detailing the **non-deprecated**, valid way of doing this.

### UPDATE:

The first half of the post is completely fixed. When I try to run `Song.find(1)`, though, it still gives the error message.

Comment: What is the reason to create Song table and then create SongInfo class which is not connected to database? Do you like to make your life harder?

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem, an extra comma in mapping, that may have nothing to do with your issue. Try this: `composed_of :songinfo, :class_name => "SongInfo", :mapping => [%w(title title)]`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed 1/2 of the problem actually :-)

Comment: @BobbyTables So what does it do now?

Comment: @BobbyTables Restart your server, create a new record, and then try it again please.

Comment: @BobbyTables  Can you change the name of the title field? I have had strange behaviors with fields named `title` and `name` and `label` etc. In the meanwhile, I am poring over your code again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12584/discussion-between-anil-and-bobby-tables)